# When creating a new room and do $location.path('/' + roomNumber); ,how can I create a new route whenever user create a new room?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

When creating a new room and do $location.path('/' + roomNumber);

is it needed to create a new route manually?

I want to develop some chat app.

What I wonder most is that "when an user create new room, and do

$location.path('/' + roomNumber); how can I create a new route whenever user create a new room?"

Comment: Don't forget that we are completely alien to what you're working on. Try to explain as clear and concise as possible what it is you're trying to do and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want linkable url you can create a new route and you can fetch the room from the server when the route is visited.

I would strongly suggest UR Router for this nstead of using location.path https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router